# Weird nbsp; issue in my html.

Tags: html, ipad

I have a question regarding a weird character of my iPad.

I am developing an existing app and it seems like the iPad displays `&nbsp;` as `Â&nbsp;` The page shows `Â` and the html is `Â&nbsp;` even thought I know the original html only contain `&nbsp;`

I am not sure what's going on here. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `&nbsp;` is not likely to cause anything like that. What do you have before the `&nbsp;` in the HTML code?

Comment: Please post an exact copy (via copy and paste) from an HTML document, with some text around the problem case, and also check a) what is the actual character encoding of the HTML file, b) how the encoding is specified in a `meta` tag and/or HTTP header.

Answer (score 1):

The file is probably saved in a character encoding that uses multiple bytes to encode ampersands.  When the ipad reads it it's probably decoding using a different character encoding.  Make sure that the encoding you're saving in matches your `<meta charset>`.  [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset)

Alternatively, if you can, save your original document in UTF-8, which is usually a good bet for a compatible default encoding.